# How to create a vector in TensorFlow.js, where the i-th entry is a scalar raised to the i-th power?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I want to create a vector in TensorFlow.js, which has the following structure:

[image: vec]

where `a` is a non-complex scalar, `n` is the length of the vector, and `i` is the `i`-th entry of the vector, starting to count at zero.

Is there a fast way of doing this or do I need to loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you could try maybe something like this:

```js
x = tf.tensor1d([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]).toInt();
y = tf.range(0, x.shape[0], 1).toInt();

x.pow(y).print();
```

```
"Tensor
    [1, 2, 9, 64, 625, 7776, 117649, 2097152]"
```